# Can I use an array as an attribute of struct in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, struct, attributes

Can I define an array of integers as an attribute in a struct in C++?

This is how I tried, output is also posted:

```cpp
struct SpaceTime{
    SpaceTime(int Coordinates[2][2]):
       Coordinates_(Coordinates[2][2]){}
public:
    int Coordinates_;
};     

int main(){
    SpaceTime earth({{100,200},{300,400}});
    std::cout << earth.Coordinates_[1][1] << std::endl;
}
```

Output from C++14, Windows 10 Visual Studio:

```
.\StackOverFlow.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\StackOverFlow.cpp:28:39: error: no matching function for call to 'SpaceTime::SpaceTime(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
  SpaceTime earth({{100,200},{300,400}});
                                       ^
.\StackOverFlow.cpp:22:5: note: candidate: SpaceTime::SpaceTime(int (*)[2])
     SpaceTime(int Coordinates[2][2]):
     ^~~~~~~~~
.\StackOverFlow.cpp:22:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int (*)[2]'
.\StackOverFlow.cpp:21:8: note: candidate: constexpr SpaceTime::SpaceTime(const SpaceTime&)    
 struct SpaceTime{
        ^~~~~~~~~
.\StackOverFlow.cpp:21:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const SpaceTime&'
.\StackOverFlow.cpp:21:8: note: candidate: constexpr SpaceTime::SpaceTime(SpaceTime&&)
.\StackOverFlow.cpp:21:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'SpaceTime&&'
.\StackOverFlow.cpp:29:35: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
  std::cout << earth.Coordinates_[1][1] << std::endl;
```

Comment: _"...does not work..."_ is not a clear description of the problem you are having.  Please post - what does not work and why.

Comment: Why have the constructor at all, since the built-in initialization will work?  `struct ST{int c[2][2];}; int main(){ auto earth = ST{{{100, 200}, {300, 400}}};` ...

Comment: Or simpler: `ST earth{ {100, 200}, {300, 400} };`

Comment: I'm not clear on which aspect you are asking about. An "attribute in a struct" means a member of the struct, as in `SpaceTime::Coordinates_`? (But you make no attempt to define `Coordinates_` as an array, only to initialize it with an array.) There is also a question of what you see as an array of integers -- someone coming from, e.g., Javascript might see `{{100,200},{300,400}}` as an array, when it is an initializer list.  Could you add more text to describe your understanding of the situation and what prompted you to write the code this way?

Comment: if you wanna something like a flexible array there - c++ doesn't support it.  C does . but this stuff you written will not work anyway.

Comment: Yes, the built-in initialization works for this simple case, but I have to made a more complex struct in my code. That is why it would be really helpful if you can tell how to do this for a parametrized constructor. @Elijay, Thank you for the reply!!!

Comment: in   c/c++ structs   attribute means `struct b {int a;} __attribute__((aligned(16))) ;` so this all comes from elsewhere for sure

Comment: I recommend: don't use a C style array, use a C++ `std::vector` (or possibly `std::array`).  Pass by value, and then do a `std::move` of the sink parameter into the member variable in the constructor's initializer list.

Comment: What you've written doesn't make sense. `Coordinates_` is a single `int`, so you can't shove something larger than that inside of it. If you want `Coordinates_` to be a different type of thing, then change the declaration of it from being just an `int`. Make it simple array or a `std::array` or `std::vector` or whatever you want in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a C++ data member may be an array.  However, your example isn't.  Your example `Coordinates_` is simply a scalar integer.  If you had wanted it to be an array, your class definition should instead appear something like this:

```
class SpaceTime {
public:
    int Coordinates_[2][2];
};
```

Also, if you want this data member to be initialized by a constructor, that construction would need to perform a deep copy of the data.